# Python, Encrypt a message with two different keys. (Crypto.PublicKey )

Tags: python, rsa, public-key

I would like to use Python to encrypt a message with two different keys.
In this situation I am using a module called `Crypto.PublicKey`.
In the following code, I can do the encryption with only one key and it is working properly.
I have tried a lot of different ways but I cannot encrypt the message with two different public keys.
I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue. 
Many thanks

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# Creating the first public key and private key
key = RSA.generate(1024)
pubKey = key.publickey().exportKey('PEM')
privKey = key.exportKey('PEM')
key = RSA.importKey(pubKey)
key1 = RSA.importKey(privKey)

# Creating the Second public key 
key_2 = RSA.generate(1024)
pubKey_2 = key_2.publickey().exportKey('PEM')
key_2 = RSA.importKey(pubKey_2)

# Message to encrypt
msg = "Message to encrypt"

# Encrypt message with only one public key
msg_encrypted = key.encrypt(msg.encode(),32)

###########################################
# Here I would like to encrypt the message with two different public key
# thus two person will have the chance two open the file with their own private key
###########################################

# Decrypt the message with the first or the second private key
msg_decrypted = key1.decrypt(msg_encrypted)

print (msg_decrypted.decode())
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I want to apologize for my question, It was not my intention to disturb. Thank very much for the advice.

Comment: I can't really see what the problem is here. You created one ciphertext with `msg_encrypted = key.encrypt(msg.encode(),32)`, so just create another with `msg_encrypted_2 = key_2.encrypt(msg.encode(),32)`. Someone with one of the two private keys will be able to decipher one of these ciphertexts to obtain the secret message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are totally right. My probelm is that i need to send the message to a bigger number of people and all this procedure will be time and resources Consuming. I hoped for an easier solution such as the possibility to add more keys in the encrptyon process. Thanks

Comment: what about this: encrypt the message with a symmetric (random) key, than include the key encrypted with the two RSA keys. You minimize the overhead by encrypting multiple times only the key, so you don't have to include multiple replica of the encrypted message.

Comment: You are not doing RSA right (that is, securely). You should use RSA OAEP instead (https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html). There is also an example for what @sigismondo describes here: https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/examples.html#encrypt-data-with-rsa.